# What solvents work on aloe vera?

Tags: solvents

I'm looking for a solvent which can fully dissolve dried aloe vera gel. I assume the main problem is the constituent polysaccharides.

Answer (score -1):

Hot water, the "universal solvent", should work nicely.

Comment: Care to elaborate? This looks more like a comment than an answer at the current moment.

Comment: Aloe vera gel is almost entirely made of water-soluble  components, or at least contains a large enough fraction of water-solubles that hot water will work nicely to clean it.